# Ios real time audio analysis battery life improvement

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerate-framework

I'm doing real time audio analysis with accelerate framework, my application consumes too much battery, how can i improve battery life without data loss in my analysis.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried and/or show us some of your code.

Comment: What functions are you using?  How are you using them?  Where is the time actually being spent in your application?  Have you used instruments to get a trace?